# Como manter o scroll do elemento sempre no bottom

Tags: jquery, rolamento

Considerem o seguinte exemplo que fiz aqui:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    $("#wrap ul").append('<li class="new">Teste</li>');
    $("li.new").slideDown('slow', 'easeOutBounce');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wagner/4FQCK/5

Como podem reparar ao clicar no botão `add` o jQuery cria um novo elemento `li` na minha lista.. Até ai tudo certo.. Notem que eu defini um `max-height` e um  `overflow: auto` no meu elemento `wrap`. O problema é que ao adicionar vários elementos dentro da minha lista, a barra de rolagem do `wrap` fica no meio dele, ao invés de se manter no `bottom` como eu gostaria.. Então minha dúvida é essa, como eu faria para que quando um novo elemento fosse adicionado a barra de rolagem não suba (lembrando que o usuário ainda deve ter a opção de rolar a barra para cima caso ele deseje ver outros itens da lista).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pode usar assim para fazer o scrol:

```
    $('#wrap').animate({                   // unsando o jQuery animate para animar o scroll
        scrollTop: $('#wrap ul').height()  // fazer scroll para a posição correspondente à altura do 'ul', o que é o mesmo que dizer scroll até ao fundo
    }, 500);                               // velocidade do scroll em milisegundos
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/J5d8b/2/)

Assim dentro do código onde adiciona um novo elemento pode ter também o código que adicionei em cima para animar um scroll. O código final será:

```
$(function () {
    $("#add").click(function () {
        var wrapUl = $("#wrap ul");
        wrapUl.append('<li class="new">Teste</li>');
        // aqui poderia usar o ':last' para evitar aplicar o slideDown a todos os elementos
        // $("li.new:last").slideDown('slow', 'easeOutBounce'); 
        $("li.new").slideDown('slow', 'easeOutBounce');                                      
        $('#wrap').animate({
            scrollTop: wrapUl.height()
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        $("#wrap ul").append('<li class="new">Teste</li>');
        $("li.new").slideDown('slow', 'easeOutBounce');
        $("#wrap").animate({scrollTop: $('#wrap').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d45Lh/2/)

Referência: [Append content to div and scroll/animate to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10777978/195417)

Achei a resposta no SOEN, e adaptei para o seu caso, então seria legal ir lá e dar um upvote pro cara, e dar o crétido!

**EDIT:** Vendo na documentação do jQuery, parece que ele suporta também efeitos, como o `"easeOutBounce"` que você usou: [documentação do animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Poxa, eu usei o fiddle original da questão para ir testando, e depois na hora de fazer o meu, esqueci de adicionar as bibliotecas sendo usadas... que mancada! Valeu @Sergio por sua observação!

Comment: Isso foi uma coisa que me ocorreu... ia tentar ver se tinha como fazer usando uma ancora ao final de todos os UL's. E acabou ficando ai sem querer.

Answer (score 1):

esse linha de código me ajudou muito, pois eu tentei manter a scroll no fim da  de varias formas mas não estava dando certo! vlw!

```
$("#wrap").animate({scrollTop: $('#wrap').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);
```